# Can an Opera mouse gesture be set to execute a user script?

Tags: javascript, opera

I used to have that with FireGestures in Firefox, and with a simple gesture I would wipe off a DOM element. (great for deleting flash advertising)
So are user scripts in opera only runnable on every page load and not under specific circumstances like keyboard strokes or mouse gestures?
If so, how?

PS: My OS is MacOS but this question is most likely OS-independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are right. Userscripts are only executed once on page load. A manual execute per keystroke/gesture is not possible.

But maybe it is possible to rewrite the userscript and add an event handler which listens to your keystroke, and that keystroke can be executed by a gesture.

http://www.opera.com/docs/userjs/examples/#loadingscripts